# AutoComplete and TextInput functionality in the same EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want my `EditText` to show its `hint` as title when gaining focus and also to display a dropdown to let the user autocomplete it. These functionality are available on `TextInputEditText` and `AutoCompleteTextView` respectively. Is there a way to achieve both besides creating a custom `EditText` using inheritance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `TextInputEditText` simply use `AutoCompleteTextView` as a child of `TextInputLayout`. Lint may show a warning but it should work just fine.

Example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: `android.support.design.widget.AutoCompleteTextView` doesn't exist as of v26.1.0

Comment: Updated. Thanks!

Comment: For API level 27, don't use `android.support.design.widget.AutoCompleteTextView`. Instead, use `<AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`

Answer (score 9):

If you want the new Material Design library and Android Jetpack components, use the following XML layout code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Example TextInputLayout">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Note that you should set the hint on `TextInputLayout` (instead of `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView`) when using this library.

If you want the alternative outlined text field version, replace `FilledBox` with `OutlinedBox` at both style properties.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I was looking for this solution for way too long